# Python scalar product with guard condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of the same shape:

```
a = numpy.array([7, 5, 0, 2, 9, 6, 4, 1])
b = numpy.array([1, 6, 3, 9, 1, 1, 3, 8])
```

I'm looking for a nice way of creating the sum product of `a` and `b` , but such that the calculation stops before reaching a limit `l`, and then returns the elements in `a` that were used for that calculation.

So in the above example, if I execute:

> `numpy.dot(a,b)`

I get `90`. However, as an example, if `l=50` what I would like instead is a function that behaves as follows:

```
>>> foo(a,b,l)
[7,5]
```

Comment: Define "nice" - Short/performant?

Comment: mmm. Good question...if I had to choose, performant. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach with `cumsum` to get summations of elementwise multiplications, then `argmax` to get the first index of limiting product summation and finally `slicing` into `a`  -

```
a[:((a*b).cumsum()>l).argmax()]
```

Sample run -

```
# Adding 2 as the third elem in 'a' for a better test
In [103]: a = np.array([7, 5, 2, 2, 9, 6, 4, 1]) 
     ...: b = np.array([1, 6, 3, 9, 1, 1, 3, 8])
     ...: 

In [104]: l = 50

In [105]: (a*b).cumsum()
Out[105]: array([ 7, 37, 43, 61, 70, 76, 88, 96])

In [106]: a[:((a*b).cumsum()>l).argmax()]
Out[106]: array([7, 5, 2])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [116]: a = np.random.randint(0,4,(10000))

In [117]: b = np.random.randint(0,4,(10000))

In [118]: l = 10000

In [119]: %timeit a[np.where((a*b).cumsum() < l)] # @wildwilhelm's soln
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.8 µs per loop

In [121]: %timeit a[(a*b).cumsum() < l] # @wildwilhelm's soln w/o np.where
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.6 µs per loop

In [122]: %timeit a[:((a*b).cumsum()>l).argmax()]
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.3 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = 50
>>> a[np.where((a*b).cumsum() < l)]
array([7, 5, 0])
```

Comment: You can avoid that `np.where`. Added that into runtime test in my post, shows some improvement.

Comment: @Dikavar +1 for timing it : )